# How to rewrite `do` block using bind with an IO read Int?

Tags: function, haskell, io, monads, do-notation

So, I want to rewrite the given `prog` function with using `>>`/`>>=` bindings instead of `do` and `<-` :

```
prog :: IO Int
     prog =
       do putStrLn "Hello there! How old are you?"
       age <- (readLn :: IO Int)
       let agedays = show $ age * 365
       putStrLn $ "So you are at least than " ++ agedays ++ " days old."
       return (read agedays)
```

Rewriting more simple functions is not a problem for me, but the `readLn :: IO Int` is giving me a headache...

My suggestion was:

```
prog :: IO Int
prog =
     putStrLn "Hello there!How old are you?" >>
     readLn::IO >>=
     let agedays = \age -> show $ age * 365 >>
     putStrLn $ "So you are at least than " ++ agedays ++ " days old."
```

However this just does not work, as there is a problem with binding the `readLn :: IO` to the next anonymous function `\age`. Any help?

Comment: shouldn't it be `(readLn :: IO Int) >>= \age -> ...`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can let the type inference do the work for you,

```
prog :: IO Int
prog =
     putStrLn "Hello there! How old are you?" >>
     readLn >>= (\ age ->
     let agedays = age * 365 in
       putStrLn ("So you are at least " ++ show agedays ++ " days old.") >>
       return agedays )
```

Since you already specify `prog :: IO Int`, it means `return agedays :: IO Int`, and `agedays :: Int`.

Then, both operands to `*` in `age * 365` must be of the same type, specifically, that of `agedays`, since we have `agedays = age * 365` there. Thus it follows that `age :: Int` already.

Answer (score 5):

You are changing the code too much, e.g. removing `Int` from `IO Int`, and inserting lambdas in the wrong points.

Something like this should work:

```
prog =
   putStrLn "Hello there! How old are you?" >>
   (readLn :: IO Int) >>= \age ->
   let agedays = show $ age * 365
   in putStrLn $ "So you are at least than " ++ agedays ++ " days old." >>
   return (read agedays)
```